# What a Gitlab administrator should do to enable Gitlab Pages?

Tags: gitlab

I've `GitLab EE` and I'm trying to figure out how `Pages` are working; I've followed everything on the official website, but I'm still getting this when trying to view repository's page settings.

> GitLab Pages are disabled. Ask your system's administrator to enable it

There is nothing about this and I really don't know how to go around.

Comment: I feel this is sort-of off-topic here. You might be better off asking a dedicated GitLab community.

Comment: I agree - I'm asking here because GitLab is well known product, so I'm hoping that there will be somebody who is more experienced than me....

Comment: @DanielB I don't agree, stack exchange sites are aggregations of questions from many communities, and this is why we found all we need here, if we are asking to the correct stack exchange site. Saying better is to ask to the gitlab community is like saying each question should be asked to the dedicated community, and super user is only for subject without a dedicated community... which is more and more rare noadays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, before ask, look at config files, my mistake.

There is no word about enabling Gitlab Pages in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` (in case of omnibus installs).

Current link to pages documentation: [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/pages/index.html)

Comment: The link to your GitLab Pages documentation is meant for Omnibus installs. So it's stated over there, change `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and set: `pages_external_url 'http://example.io'`. Still it doesn't work in my case, the reconfigure fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you run into bind mount issue when using docker volume you'll also need to set this:

```
gitlab_pages['inplace_chroot'] = true
```

Comment: In docker env it's work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running omnibus install. As per [documentation](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/administration.html) in the simplest case, with no custom domains or SSL, in order to enable pages, all you have to do is, set `pages_external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` config file.

```
####################
# GitLab Pages
####################

## Define to enable GitLab Pages
pages_external_url "http://pages.foo.com/"
```

As per @Melroy comment, you may also need to set

```
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
```

Comment: I'm getting: 

```2018-05-03_22:56:29.19417 time="2018-05-04T00:56:29+02:00" level=info msg="GitLab Pages Daemon" revision=b77d612 version=dev
2018-05-03_22:56:29.19423 time="2018-05-04T00:56:29+02:00" level=info msg="URL: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages"
2018-05-03_22:56:29.19426 time="2018-05-04T00:56:29+02:00" level=info msg="running the daemon as unprivileged user" gid=998 in-place=false uid=998
```

Comment: So it seems that setting this pages_external_url is not enough! I needed to also set: `gitlab_pages['enable'] = true` and set `gitlab_pages['external_http']= 'ip:port'`

Answer (score 1):

One more thing, since the following information is written nowhere but seems "obvious", you need to let the gitlab-runner build your static site **after** having set `gitlab_pages['enable'] = true` and `gitlab_pages['inplace_chroot'] = true` when using gitlab docker image and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

In my case, I add to force a previously succeeded Job using the `Retry` button in order to publish the static build. Immediately after this, the `Project` -> `Settings` -> `Pages` menu was updated with the usable link.

- [French tutorial about gitlab-pages](http://mboileau.pages.math.cnrs.fr/gitlab-pages/gitlab-pages.html)
- [gitlab_pages.py script that list all enabled static sites](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/boileaum/e28486a4a2f0e0f520fa35a410f96400/raw/9cb164d402f10ff409cb4efec2da26e68b1a8024/gitlab_pages.py)